# Why is my request filling 2 fields? I make one request

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function SalesSave(Request $req) {
    $rules = [
        'date' => 'required|min:4|max:36',
        'earnings' => 'min:1|max:16',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($req->all(), $rules);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
    }
    SalesModel::create($req->all());
    $us = Auth::id();
    DB::table('sales')->insertGetId(['date' => $req->query('date'), 'id' => $us, 'earnings' => $req->query('earnings')]);
    return redirect('/sale');
}
```

and 2 fields in db
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98mJm.png)
I need this data in one field, how to fix it?

Comment: Please add more context to your question. Just posting the code alone without context makes it really hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your query you are using the wrong method to get the values.
Instead of `$req->query('date')` put `$req->input('date')` do the same for `earnings`

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting it twice:

1st:

```
SalesModel::create($req->all());
```

2nd:

```
DB::table('sales')->insertGetId(['date' => $req->query('date'), 'id' => $us, 'earnings' => $req->query('earnings')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this :

```
public function SalesSave(Request $req) {
    $rules = [
        'date' => 'required|min:4|max:36',
        'earnings' => 'min:1|max:16',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($req->all(), $rules);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
    }
    $us = Auth::id();
    SalesModel::create([
        'date' => $req->date, 
        'id' => $us, 
        'earnings' => $req->earnings
    ]);
    
    return redirect('/sale');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
public function SalesSave(Request $req) {
$rules = [
    'date' => 'required|min:4|max:36',
    'earnings' => 'min:1|max:16',
];

$validator = Validator::make($req->all(), $rules);
if($validator->fails()){
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
}
$inputs['id']=Auth::id();
$inputs['date']=$req->date;
$inputs['earnings'] =$req->earnings;
SalesModel::create($inputs);
return redirect('/sale');
```

}